# Log4j file appender for each instance of a class

Tags: java, log4j, fileappender

I have a scenario class, which has list of Test cases. Is there any way that I can save each Test case execution to separate file with name: `TestCaseName.log`?

I have done this before with `java.util.logging` by adding file handler in the code, but have no idea how to do this with Log4j.

Comment: @RKC Your edit should have been rejected. Do not, ever, add "Pls Help" to the end of someone's answer. I'll be looking into who approved that edit and potentially flagging for some special moderator attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Task was completed by adding RollingFileAppenders programmatically, just like in this example:
http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/08/how-to-programmatically-configure-appenders-in-log4j/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by configuring a separate `org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender` for each Test case class.
You can check the link http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html for configuring this.

Comment: There is only one class "TestCase", I need to separate logging for each instance of this class